# Value of $\int _0^{+\infty }\:e^{-x²}\cdot \sqrt{\sinh^2\left(x\right)+1}dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Can somebody help me find the value of

$\int _0^{+\infty }\:e^{-x^2}\cdot \sqrt{\sinh^2\left(x\right)+1}dx$

without using any special integral (so no erf)

I keep getting stuck trying to solve the integral with the following integral

$\int _0^{+\infty }\:\frac{\sqrt{e^{-2x}+e^{2x}+2}}{2e^{x^2}}dx$

a different method gave me

$\int _0^{+\infty }\:\left(e^{-x^2+x}+e^{-x^2-x}\right)dx$

Comment: Hint: $\sinh^2x+1=\cosh^2 x.$

Comment: I tried using that but I end up with the second integral if I try that.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The function is even therefore

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cosh x\:dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2+x}\:dx$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Am I not supposed to solve the indefinite integral itself because I always end up stuck trying to solve the indefinite integral.

Comment: @Savantik Most advanced integrals are impossible for humans with trying to solve for an indefinite integral. This integral, the Gaussian, is famously inexpressible as an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions

Comment: @Savantik how would you get the $\sqrt{\pi}$ without an erf then if you want an indefinite integral? The usual method to "avoid" special functions is knowing the Gaussian result and leveraging it.

Comment: Well I don't know either, this one is in my textbook so I have no idea, maybe it it solvable by using series?

Comment: @Savantik no that is very incorrect - the series are not uniformly convergent so you are not allowed to swap the integral and sum. The question was rhetorical - I'm saying with complete confidence that knowing and using the Gaussian result is the expected solution "without" special functions.

Comment: So it is impossible witthout the Gaussian integral?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As suggested by @ThomasAndrews, one gets
\begin{align*}
\exp(-x^{2})\sqrt{\sinh^{2}(x) + 1} & = \exp(-x^{2})\cosh(x)\\\\
& = \exp(-x^{2})\left(\frac{\exp(x) + \exp(-x)}{2}\right)\\\\
& = \frac{\exp(-x^{2} + x) + \exp(-x^{2} - x)}{2}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left[\exp\left(-\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\right) + \exp\left(-\left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\right)\right]
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Oh, yes I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Since the integrand is even and the improper integrals clearly converge: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cosh(x)\d x=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cosh(x)\d x$$And: $$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cosh(x)\d x&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x-x^2}\d x+\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+x)}\d x\right]\\&=\frac{e^{1/4}}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-1/2)^2}\d x+\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+1/2)^2}\d x\right]\\&=\frac{e^{1/4}}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\d x+\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\d x\right]\\&=e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}\end{align}$$

So you have: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cosh(x)\d x=\frac{1}{2}e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the $\sqrt{\pi }$ from, atleast I've never learned that.

Comment: @Savantik It is the Gaussian integral. You cannot evaluate this integral without also evaluating (implicitly) the Gaussian, so you may as well learn the Gaussian and apply it here